# Change where Ansible looks for files

Tags: ansible

My directory structure looks like this

```
playbooks/
  Foo.yml
  tasks/
    Task1.yml
    Task2.yml
    AllTasks.yml
```

The `Foo.yml` playbook has a `- import_tasks: tasks/AllTasks.yml` task. `AllTasks.yml` has

```
- import_tasks: tasks/Task1.yml
- import_tasks: tasks/Task2.yml
```

This works perfectly fine when I execute playbook `Foo.yml`. But when I execute a playbook located elsewhere (so not directly in this `playbooks` directory), the imports no longer work. The reason for this is that they import relative to the location of the imported playbook.

The same happens with tasks using other modules, such as copy. They look for files relative to the playbook location.

Is there a way to make my tasks work for playbooks located in different directories?

I know there is a `playbook_dir` variable which sadly I cannot override. I also came across `inventory_dir`, but for whatever reason that one is not defined.

A way to reference files relative to the file the reference is made in would work. Example:

```
- import_tasks: "{{ current_dir }}/Task1.yml"
- import_tasks: "{{ current_dir }}/Task2.yml"
```

Something relative to the inventory file of this project would also work. Example:

```
- import_tasks: "{{ inventory_dir }}/playbooks/tasks/Task1.yml"
- import_tasks: "{{ inventory_dir }}/playbooks/tasks/Task2.yml"
```

This latter approach would force me to add these paths all over the project though.

Comment: Thanks. I have corrected the example. It is just an example with similar structure to my actual project.

Answer (score 0):

Q: **"*playbook_dir variable which sadly I cannot override*"**

A: The variable [playbook_dir](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#special-variables) works as expected (but it's not needed in this case; see the second part under the line)

```yaml
shell> cd /scratch/tmp
shell> cat Foo.yml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - import_tasks: "{{ playbook_dir }}/tasks/AllTasks.yml"
```

```yaml
shell> cat tasks/AllTasks.yml
- import_tasks: "{{ playbook_dir }}/tasks/Task1.yml"
- import_tasks: "{{ playbook_dir }}/tasks/Task2.yml"
```

```yaml
shell> cat tasks/Task1.yml 
- debug:
    msg: Task1.yml
```

```yaml
shell> cat tasks/Task2.yml 
- debug:
    msg: Task2.yml
```

```yaml
shell> cd /tmp
shell> pwd
/tmp
shell> ansible-playbook /scratch/tmp/Foo.yml

PLAY [localhost] ****

TASK [debug] ****
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Task1.yml"
}

TASK [debug] ****
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Task2.yml"
}

PLAY RECAP ****
localhost: ok=2 changed=0 unreachable=0 failed=0 skipped=0 rescued=0 ignored=0
```

---

Q: **"*Change where Ansible looks for files*"**

A: No changes are needed. The defaults work fine. See [Search paths in Ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbook_pathing.html#search-paths-in-ansible). The values of the variable *ansible_search_path* below explain why the paths are working

```yaml
shell> cat Foo.yml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: ansible_search_path
    - import_tasks: tasks/AllTasks.yml

shell> cat tasks/AllTasks.yml
- debug:
    var: ansible_search_path
- import_tasks: Task1.yml
- import_tasks: Task2.yml

shell> cat tasks/Task1.yml
- debug:
    msg: Task1.yml

shell> cat tasks/Task2.yml
- debug:
    msg: Task2.yml
```

give

```yaml
    "ansible_search_path": [
        "/scratch/tmp"
    ]

    "ansible_search_path": [
        "/scratch/tmp/tasks",
        "/scratch/tmp"
    ]

    "msg": "Task1.yml"

    "msg": "Task2.yml"
```